# C#, Accord, FileNotFoundException when try to download MNIST

Tags: c#, mnist, accord.net

Quick question.

I want to download a MNIST dataset to my C# project.

In [Accord documentation](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_DataSets_MNIST.htm) you can read:

```
Downloads and prepares the MNIST dataset.

public MNIST(
string path = null
)

Parameters
path (Optional)
Type: System.String
    The path where datasets will be stored. If null or empty, the dataset 
    will be saved on a subfolder called "data" in the current working directory.
```

I think, it will be preatty easy, so according (feel the joke) to the documentation i go into C# Program and write this:

```
using System;
using Accord.DataSets;
using System.IO;

namespace ML.NET_Mnist
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MNIST dataset = new MNIST();         
        }
    }
}
```

As output, i get this:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'SharpZipLib.NETStandard, Version=0.86.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

I cant find any solutions in Google or StackOverflow so i ask you, could you know how to download MNIST dataset and work with it with C# program? Accord-way looks preatty easy, but like you see it not work for me as espected.

There is method named [Download](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_DataSets_Base_SparseDataSet_Download.htm), but what is properly URL of MNIST dataset?

Comment: Did you install [SharpZipLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib.NETStandard/)?

Comment: @jsanalytics I installed SharpZipLip in `ver 1,0` first, the same error. Downgraded to version `0.86`, still the same exception. I think its a bug in an accord framework. They didnt update it by year, issues on github are dead. I think. I think authors lost their interest in Accord

Comment: @jsanalytics look into my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found Solution, `SharpZipLib` is not supported by `.NET Core`, so if you want to use `Accord.Datasets` in your project, you need to use `.NETFramework` instead of `Core` (im talking about console app) because that namespace appeals to `SharpZipLib`